# Reliable websockets server to handle atleast thousand connections simulteneously

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I've been using socket.io (v 0.9) for sometime now to handle around 1000 simultaneous connections. The server stop responding reliably after running for 3-4 days and needs a restart. When in "hung" state, I do not see any error when websockets requests hit the server, they just do not go through.

I've used tornado (python) earlier but it lacked SSL support so we moved out of it. WSS support is a must. Is there anything more reliable which I could try out (should be easy to integrate). I do no need the long polling and other stuff that socket.io offers, just reliable websockets would do.

Comment: Are you sure the websocket connector is the problem? 1K connections should be no problem whatsoever. You probably have the problem somewhere else. Is a .NET component ok for you?

Comment: No, I'm very sure this has something to do with socket.io stability. It runs well for 3-4 days and then starts developing issue. After this some requests are responded to and some are not.  I'm looking at other nodejs solutions like WS and engine.io right now.